# force to change text on title element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html page and there is some javascript that change text to title element when after page load.
But the text is wrong and I cannot find the JS file.

So I want to force to change the text when after page load.

For example,
Now when page loaded, code look like this.

```
<title>old text</title>
```

But I want to change text after page load like this.

```
<title>new title blah blah blah</title>
```

This is what I tried. But not working to me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = 'new title blah blah blah';
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Checked your console for errors? Are you loading jQuery? That code should work fine.

Comment: @ j08691  // Oh thanks. I forget to load jquery. problem solved :)

Comment: document.title will help you to change the title dynamic create the instance for title.. but when you see the source code of the page on the browser Cont+U it will be empty

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your text forcefully like this

```
    <head>
    <title>Text format</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script>
    $('title').html('title Content bla bla bla bla bla');

   </script>

   </body>
```

I think it will be helpful for you.